# SQL Server error login failed for user

Tags: sql, dns, connect, sql-server-2016

i had installed sql on local system nad no problem , but now my system join to domain i cannot connect to sql server with no user.
details error below:

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to RD7.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Login failed for user 'karans\mohammad.ghasemi'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

Comment: How are you trying to connect?  Management Studio?

Comment: are you using SSMS to connect to  SQL server?

Comment: Did you choose mixed mode when you installed SQL? If so try connecting using sa and add your domain log in to the users group.

Comment: yes @JonathanWillcock

Comment: yes @RohitPoudel

Comment: make sure you choose mix mode authentication and sql -server is running too if you are using the correct authentication. @mohammad ghasemi

Comment: i use it windows authentication , i dont khnow what that is mix mode, pelease say me that what do i do, @RohitPoudel

Comment: @mohammadghasemi.better change the authentication mode of server for login .here links describe about mixed mode authentication https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode

Comment: @RohitPoudel Without being able to open Management Studio, he will not be able to change mode of existing instance???

Comment: i can not connect anything , no win authentication, no server authentication , no sa no etc , ...becuse write there : In SQL Server Management Studio Object Explorer, right-click the server, and then click Properties. @RohitPoudel

Comment: no , may be i dont khnow . @RohitPoudel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you will need to do, is to log out of your domain.  You should still be able to log on to your machine using your old local account, via machinename\oldusername combo.  Once logged on, you should be able to open Management Studio.  Now you can switch to mixed mode (always advisable IMHO).  Also as a precaution, add yourself a new user being your new domain user and give yourself all the rights you need.  Now when you re-logon to domain, you should be able to open Management Studio.

There is an easier alternative which may work for you.  Try right-clicking your Management Studio icon.  If you are lucky you can go Run As and give your local user as the user.  (With Windows 10 and Sql Server 2016 this is no longer an option, but it certainly used to be on earlier versions).

HTH